# Creating AWS AppSync using AWS Lambda (NodeJS)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, graphql, graphql-js, aws-appsync

In my project, we create tables in AWS dynamodb based on the user id using AWS lambda (NodeJS).

Once the table is created the lambda function will create a graphql endpoint for that particular table so that the user can get real-time data for that specific table.

Can we create graphql endpoints which will also be seen in AWS appsync from AWS lambda (NodeJs)?

I searched the web but didn't find any tutorial from AWS nor any articles regarding it.

Comment: If your GraphQL endpoint is exposed through HTTP, then you can use an HTTP resolver to query your endpoint through AppSync.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well to be frank its will be very hard to achieve such functionality but if you still required then yes you can do that using AWS AppSync SDK

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/AppSync.html

From you tags assuming that you are using javascript.

**Just my suggestion** :- Dont try to do such things as it wont be easy to manage multiple app async and cost will increased x10

Comment: First of all thanks for reaching out to such an old question, I have changed the way I was implementing in order to save the AWS billing, and just recently I came to know about this SDK with the help of it we can implement it.